# Java displaying HTML

Tags: java, html, swing

I'm trying to display HTML that I received from a server.  However, the current code is only working for very *few* and *simple* HTML code (e.g. bad request pages).

This is a sample of very simple HTML that I cannot manage to display with my current code.

```
 <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
 <TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
 <H1>302 Moved</H1>
 The document has moved
 <A HREF="http://www.google.be/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=uhoTU6CaDoSNOrHrgeAL">here</A>.
 </BODY></HTML>
```

Here is my code which runs inside a `JFrame`.

```
JEditorPane ed1 = new JEditorPane("text/html", content);
add(ed1);
setVisible(true);
setSize(600,600);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Note that `content` is just a string with every line of HTML concatenated to one another.  Like so: `content = "<HTML>.............</HTML>"`

There might be more elegant solutions to fetching server responses and displaying them. But, I am restricted to the `java.io` and `java.net` packages.

Comment: remove the `<meta/>` tag and give a try.

Comment: that does seem to resolve the issue I had with this response. Thank you!

Comment: More information. What does "not working" mean? Show us a simple example of input and failing output. Remember that JEditorPane *isn't* a browser and isn't going to render most of the tags for you.

Comment: @keshlam the html code above is the failing input, resulting in an empty window. Do you know an alternative to what I am trying to do? Something more browser-like perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code writes the HTML to a file and then proceeds to open this file with the default browser.

```
File file = new File("test.html");
try {
    Files.write(file.toPath(), content.getBytes());
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(file.toURI());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The HTML support in JEditorPane is pretty basic, essentially HTML 3.2 with very limited support for styling. You may want to try an alternative renderer component such as [flying saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), which does a much better job of more modern standards such as XHTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
JEditorPane edit1 = new JEditorPane("text/html",content);
```

Have you tried to replace `text/html` with `text/plain` so that it is considered as plain text and not HTML?